# Get rid of extra white space inserted when using \verb with tabularx

Tags: tables, tabularx, verbatim

I noticed a peculiar behavior of `tabularx` when using `\verb`. The following minimal working example illustrates the problem.

Note the wicked extra space introduced between `test` and `{123}`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\verb|tabular|

\begin{tabular}{|l|}
\hline
\verb|\test{123}{}{} \foo{} \bar{}|\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\verb|tabularx|

\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{|X|}
\hline
\verb|\test{123}{}{} \foo{} \bar{}|\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It seems like the content of `\verb|***|` is parsed in the case of tabularx. This is best seen if `\verb||` contains non-paired curly braces: `\verb|open-brace:{|`. This normally would not cause a problem. If used within tabularx, however, it leads to an error.

How can I use `\verb` normally within a tabularx? How can I get rid of these extra spaces?

Comment: On the console and in the .log-file I get the warning `LaTeX Warning: \verb may be unreliable inside tabularx on input line 20.`

Comment: @UlrichDiez Ah, didn't pay attention to this. Is there an alternative way of printing code verbatim within tabularx? Or do I have to mimic the behavior of `\verb`, like this:  `\texttt{\textbackslash test\{123\}}`...

Comment: it'a not peculiar behaviour, it's a documented feature, see the tabularx manual.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle True! I should have had a look at it. Sorry for framing the question this way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `\Verb` from `fancyvrb`, but with the better definition provided by `fvextra`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{fvextra}

\begin{document}

\Verb|tabular|

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|l|}
\hline
\Verb|\test{123}{}{} \foo{} \bar{}|\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\Verb|tabularx|

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{|X|}
\hline
\Verb|\test{123}{}{} \foo{} \bar{}|\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\verb|tabular|

\begin{tabular}{|l|}
\hline
\verb|\test{123}{}{} \foo{} \bar{}|\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\verb|tabularx|

\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{|X|}
\hline
\texttt{\string\test\{123\}\{\}\{\} \string\foo\{\} \string\bar\{\}}\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or try find some cool way to paste your code using this book :) https://github.com/AnMnv/eBook

Comment: That's odd - the curly brackets put inside `\textt` aren't in `tt`.  Which is also why the later characters in the 2 examples don't line up